# "Традиция хранится по сторонам дорог" - в контексте это может сойти?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

> Остерия. В отличие от таверны остерия означает гостеприимный дом, в
>   котором рады путнику. Такая народная традиция хранится ещё по сторонам
>   древних дорог, по которым и сегодня, например из Флоренции в Болонью,
>   можно совершить увлекательное путешествие пешком.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если традиция - это ресторан с итальянской кухней (остерия), то возможно, но всё же лучше "вдоль дорог", а не "по сторонам дорог".